# Uninstall tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having problems with uninstalling TensorFlow.

I have a Python script that uses TensorFlow. I want it to use TensorFlow1.15, but it is currently using TensorFlow 2.1.0. I deleted TensorFlow via my cmd: `pip uninstall tensorflow` and `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu`. When I run these commands again it says that TensorFlow is not installed. However, I can see that my script says it is using TensorFlow 2.1.0 (I added the line:`print(tf.__version__)` in my script). Does anyone know where this TensorFlow 2.1.0 is installed and how I can delete it from my PC?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: `pip` might be pointing at a different location then your `python` script, you should try doing `python -m pip uninstall tensorflow` or better yet use a virtual environment

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. I wonder if a reboot would eliminate your problem? Also, please be aware that an uninstall from Anaconda might not change the virtual environment in, say, PyCharm.

Comment: Yes I have tried python -m uninstall tensorflow as well! It also says that I don't have tensorflow

Comment: I rebooted my pc, but it doesn't have any effect. Do you know how I can uninstall tensorflow from PyCharm?

Comment: I use Windows 10 Home

Comment: it would be really easy for you if you use anaconda for managing environment

Answer (score 2):

Also you can downgrade `tensorflow` by this command in Pycharm `terminal` :

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow==1.15
```

It can also be used for other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This problem means that you use different pythons in your terminal and your script.

You mentioned PyCharm. By default, it creates a virtual environment for a new project. It also can use your global python. In any case, open a terminal in PyCharm (it should be in the bottom of the window or `View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal` or `Option + F12` on Mac, `Alt + F12` on Windows). From there you should run `pip uninstall tensorflow`. PyCharm automatically activates the correct python environment in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

From the above-provided information it is difficult to ascertain the scenario in which you are trying to uninstall.
I suggest creating a new python environment for your project using anaconda-

follow these steps -

1. download exe file for [Anaconda website](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section)
2. install it.
3. open cmd
4. create new env using this command `conda create -n yourenvname python=3.6`
5. install tensorflow 1.15 by `conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.15`
6. go to pycharm select your new conda environment.(File -> setting -> project -> project interpreter - > insert path for env)

your env in windows might be in windows installation drive - > users -> anaconda3 -> envs

Comment: I have installed anaconda. When I run 4 in anaconda, besides saying I need to update anaconda. When running 5, it says: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:  - tensorflow-gpu==1.5. Lastly, how do I select conda environment in pycharm?

Comment: Try conda install -c default tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0 also conda update conda to update anconda packages

Comment: I have mentioned how to choose anaconda on pycharm in point - 6

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand point 6. I have successfully installed tensorflow 1.15 now. Should I import the env package in my interpreter?

Comment: Yes there is a + button in add env option there you can choose the path of the env ( select add existing environment )

Comment: Yess it worked! However I can't install packages anymore. I use numpy, matplotlib, PIL, tensorflow, cv2 and utils. When I try to download any of them I get an error:CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>

Answer (score 0):

File ->Setting
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now you '+' button on rightmost tool bar "click" it
finally installed package

if still package is not installed or pycharm showing error then you have to remove tensorflow from base root and reinstall it

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I did this, but when I print my tensorflow version, I still have 2.1.0

Comment: I am making a program that can detect objects. I have an attribute error: tensorflow has no attribute 'graphdef'. Someone else helped me and told me I have the wrong version of tensorflow. According to him I need tensorflow 1.15. When I print: print(tf.__version__), in my program it says: 2.1.0, so the program says I have tensorflow 2.1.0

Comment: I also face this problem  Do not try to switch to tensorflow==2.0 you should update your code that's what i did

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822617/python-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-graphdef-and-cudart64-101-dll-not-found/59823086#59823086    visit this may be help you